# QSqlQuery insert full struct instead of individual fields?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

Following [`QSqlQuery Class` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html) one can implemented an insert operation in a MySQL database, i.e. like this:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
              "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
query.exec();
```

It works. But it's fragile, isn't? It will stop working (because names are hard coded) when a column name mismatch occurs, if the database programmer changes a column name in the MySQL script, i.e. `surname` to `lastname`.

What came to my mind was to change the whole mechanism so that instead of inserting individual fields one big object (perhaps a struct composed by the individual fields) should be inserted. And then, in the db side, the fields should be split back into a set of fields, i.e. using a view or a trigger.

Am I going in the right direction?

I'll appreciate general comments on the issue.

Comment: so, are you looking for some way of implementation where you can change the column from `surname` to `lastname` in the db, and then the C++ code will automatically know that values that were supposed to go into `surname` will now go into `lastname` without any change in the C++ side??

Comment: Not exactly, but since you came with this related question may be you have an answer for your own question (which is very close to mine - question edited trying to make my approach more clear) and in this case I'm interested in your approach. Do you know some way to offload the query and load it at run time?

Comment: sorry, in fact I was asking my question because I think there is no way to implement that. Maybe someone here can correct me. . .

Comment: I think that there is no way for the C++ code to know without any change that `lastname` column replaced the `surname` column. I really think that any change in the db schema, will have its effects on the C++ code that uses it no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way, but you must be sure that structure of the table and column meaning wouldn't change and your query has data of each column to insert.

Firstly, you must select all information about your table:

```
SELECT c.column_name FROM information_schema.columns c 
WHERE c.table_name = 'some_table_name' 
ORDER BY c.ordinal_position ASC
```

Secondly, your code can be change like this. I am using universal method that meaning you have already known data:

```
QList<QVariant> valuesList { QVariant(1), QVariant("Bart"), QVariant("Simpson") }; 
QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> varList;
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_num, c.column_name 
            FROM information_schema.columns c, (SELECT @rownum := -1) r
            WHERE c.table_name = 'some_table_name' 
            ORDER BY c.ordinal_position ASC");
while(query.next())
    colList << QPair<QString, QString>(query.value(1).toString(), 
               valuesList.at(query.value(0).toInt()));

QString queryString = "INSERT INTO person (%1) "
                      "VALUES (%2)";

QString insertColsString;
QString bindColsString;

for(int i = 0; i < colList.size(); i++) {
    insertColsString += colList.at(i).first + ", ";
    bindColsString += ":" colList.at(i).first + ", ";
}

if(!insertColsString.isEmpty()) {
    insertColsString.chop(2);
    bindColsString.chop(2);
}

query.prepare(queryString.arg(insertColsString, bindColsString));

for(int i = 0; i < colList.size(); i++)
    query.bindValue(":" + colList.at(i).first, colList.at(i).second);

query.exec();
```